# How to display custom field content type to template page in page--front.html.twig?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal & Curruntly learning on Drupal 8. I want to create HTML to Drupal dynamic conversion.

So for that I have created page--front.html.twig & Dynamic created page from backend as "Home Page" as front page. Hence It will automatically select the page--front.html.twig template. (Here I already added content type as Home page with custom fields)

Here for HTML to drupal first conversion All HTML codes I putted in page--front.html.twig & its related css & Js. So it will display static content.

Now I want to get all section content dynamically. So I have created other fields to that content type added some content into it but now I could not get that custom field value in template Front page using {{ content.field_test_field }}

I have used below codes,

```
{{ dump(content|keys) }}
{{ content.field_third_section_content.0 }}
{{ fields.field_third_section_content.content }}
{{ node.body.value|raw }}
{{ content.field_third_section_content }}
{{ node.field_third_section_content.0.value }}
{{ node.teaser.value }}

{{ dump(content|keys) }} for this I got array(0) { }
```

, Please give me some brief explanation So can know more about it syntax and functionality. & all above code is not working for me.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display fields for page--front.html.twig using the output types below :

Remember to replace FIELDNAME with the name of your field.

**Outputting Blocks:** {{ page.REGIONNAME }}

**Outputting Page Title:** 
{{ node.title.value }}

**Outputting a Taxonomy Term or Dropdown Select option:** 
{{ node.field_FIELDNAME.0.entity.label }}

**Outputting General Text Fields:** 
{{ node.field_FIELDNAME.value }}

**Outputting Images or Files:** 
{{ file_url(node.field_FIELDNAME.entity.fileuri')) }}

Comment: Thank you for response.

 I have used {{ node.field_second_section_left.value }} and it's working for displaying content but it display with html tags in out put. Like I displayed in https://nimb.ws/2SJ5Y3 this link (I have used custom field as text editor).

Please help me to solve this problem. & It will display with designs as per I given in html tag.

Comment: Try : {{ node.field_second_section_left.value | raw }}

Answer (score 0):

The dump() function will not display any output unless debugging is enabled.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374